# Merge Mutual-Fund and Mutual-Funds Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

We Need to create a tag synonym for [mutual-funds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-funds) as [mutual-fund](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-fund).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this got merged, so marking it complete.